# PyQt5: how to move sub widgets into main window?

Tags: python, pyqt5, signals-slots

This code opens 3 separate windows:

```
1) main window
2) widgetA 
3) widgetB.
```

**How to write the code in such a way that it moves 2 and 3 into 1?**

So we just have one main window and in it 2 widgets that can communicate with each other. Also, an additional feature: how can we write a function in such a way that it listens to incoming data and then sends it away?

```
class mainwindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(mainwindow, self).__init__(parent)

        self.button = QtWidgets.QPushButton("Click Me", self)
        self.button.clicked.connect(self.on_button_clicked)

        self.setCentralWidget(self.button)

        self.widgetA = widgetA()
        self.widgetB = widgetB()

        self.widgetA.procStart.connect(self.widgetB.on_procStart)
        self.widgetB.procDone.connect(self.widgetA.on_widgetB_procDone)

    @QtCore.pyqtSlot()
    def on_button_clicked(self):
        self.widgetA.show()
        self.widgetB.show()

        self.widgetA.raise_()

class widgetA(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    procStart = QtCore.pyqtSignal(str)

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(widgetA, self).__init__(parent)

        self.lineEdit = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self)
        self.lineEdit.setText("Hello!")

        self.button = QtWidgets.QPushButton("Send Message to B", self)
        self.button.clicked.connect(self.on_button_clicked)

        self.layout = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout(self)
        self.layout.addWidget(self.lineEdit)
        self.layout.addWidget(self.button)

    @QtCore.pyqtSlot()
    def on_button_clicked(self):
        self.procStart.emit(self.lineEdit.text())

    @QtCore.pyqtSlot(str)
    def on_widgetB_procDone(self, message):
        self.lineEdit.setText("From B: " + message)

        self.raise_()


class widgetB(QtWidgets.QWidget):

    procDone = QtCore.pyqtSignal(str)

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(widgetB, self).__init__(parent)

        self.lineEdit = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self)
        self.button = QtWidgets.QPushButton("Send Message to A", self)
        self.layout = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout(self)
        self.layout.addWidget(self.lineEdit)
        self.layout.addWidget(self.button)

        self.button.clicked.connect(self.on_button_clicked)

    @QtCore.pyqtSlot()
    def on_button_clicked(self):
        self.procDone.emit(self.lineEdit.text())

    @QtCore.pyqtSlot(str)
    def on_procStart(self, message):
        self.lineEdit.setText("From A: " + message)

        self.raise_()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys

    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    main = mainwindow()
    main.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need to show more than one widget into a "top level window" (no matter if it's a QWidget, a QDialog or a QMainWindow) you need to create a *container* widget.

In your case you're using a QMainWindow, which is a *very* special kind of QWidget, as it has its own (internal and almost unaccessible) layout. The main content that is normally shown within a QMainWindow (besides its menubar, statusbar, toolbars and dockbars) is called the "central widget", and you're setting it to a QPushButton, so there's no *room* for anything else.

The most common and conventional approach is to create a new QWidget (which is an empty widget that is used as the basis for *all* Qt widgets), set a layout for it and add the actual widgets to it:

```
class mainwindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(mainwindow, self).__init__(parent)

        container = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        self.setCentralWidget(container)
        # using a widget as an argument in a Qt layout constructor results in 
        # automatically setting the layout for that widget
        layout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(container)

        self.button = QtWidgets.QPushButton("Click Me", self)
        self.button.clicked.connect(self.on_button_clicked)

        self.widgetA = widgetA()
        self.widgetB = widgetB()

        layout.addWidget(self.button)
        layout.addWidget(self.widgetA)
        layout.addWidget(self.widgetB)
        # ...
```

Note that if you're not using QMainWindow but a standard QWidget or QDialog, you obviously don't need to use the "central widget", and you can just create a new layout on the current instance (`self`).

```
class SomeWidget(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)
        layout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self)
        # ...
```

Comment: Hey thank you kindly; I've followed your steps however I am not able to send the messages through. When I click for example send message to B; A doesn't receive the text written. In fact it doesn't do anything. I run the code through terminal and I don't see any errors pop up either..

Comment: Also another question: what if I wanted another chat box that only has the ability of reading the message that widget A sends; so a new widget that is subscribed to the widget A. Another way is to think about is that widget A broadcasts its message to widgets A is connected with.

Comment: @wecandothis 1. Calm down. 2. I merged my code with yours and it works; have you connected the `procStart` and `procDone` signals? We cannot do everything for you, I just posted the important parts *related to the question*, you shall do the rest (see the `# ...` at the end of my code). 3. We are not here 24/7, we might have other things to do and might not have time to answer instantly just because you are in a hurry. 4. Insulting won't help you in **no** way. In fact, it might result in people *not* answering you because of that. I strongly suggest you to change your behavior for the future.

Comment: Note that your last comment has been flagged. Repeated behavior like that normally results in banning.

Comment: Yes mate, I've connected specifically your dots #... and it does not do anything; no faults in the code whatsoever, no errors at all, confusing as hell

Comment: As said I just tested it and it correctly sends the messages between the widgets. I've taken your original code, I altered it with my modifications, that's it. If you added the connections as in your original example, it will work, otherwise I really don't know what to tell you.

Comment: I don't know mate I will have to look later into it I guess